# Click event does not fire on Google Maps when using a touch device

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am viewing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events using the device mode of the Chrome Developer Tools. When I touch the map, the click event clearly fires.

I have an Angular app based on Cordova that includes the Google Maps JavaScript API (3). I am trying to place a marker on the position where the map was touched, but when I subscribe to the click event myself, it is never fired.

```
_map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
    center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
    },

    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoom: 8
});

google.maps.event.addListener(_map, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log('This never happens');
});
```

Funny enough, the `dblclick` event does work with touch. I could leverage `mousedown` to get touch working, but since this also triggers when you start dragging, this is not really an option. Everything works flawlessly when using the mouse.

Any clue to what is wrong here very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps tend not to recognise touch events, a useful workaround is to bind `mousedown` event instead of click.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(_map, 'mousedown', function(event) {
    console.log("Can't touch this");
});
```

**Edited**
As Laurens stated in the comments the `touch` events nor the double click is working on touch devices.
I have thought one possible workaround:

Detect touch events before fetching the  map and still bind the click event

```
var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    if(isTouch)
        console.log("Touched");
    else    
        console.log("Can't touch this");
});
```

Comment: Hi Theodore, thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately, I wish to place a marker where the map was touched, and mousedown also triggers when you start dragging so that is not an option.

Comment: mouseup then might be what you need.

Comment: `mouseup` would fire at the end of a dragging action, so it would suffer from the same problem. I just clarified in my original question that the `dblclick` does seem to work with touch. This strikes me as odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mousedown instead of click.